# how do I resolve docker issues with ice login?

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I am using use the ice command line interface for IBM Container Services, and I am seeing a couple of different problems from a couple of different boxes I am testing with.  Here is one example:

```
[root@cds-legacy-monitor ~]# ice --verbose login --org chrisr@ca.ibm.com --space dev --user chrisr@ca.ibm.com --registry registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net
@2015-11-26 01:38:26.092288 - Namespace(api_key=None, api_url=None, cf=False, cloud=False, host=None, local=False, org='chrisr@ca.ibm.com', psswd=None, reg_host='registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net', skip_docker=False, space='dev', subparser_name='login', user='chrisr@ca.ibm.com', verbose=True)
@2015-11-26 01:38:26.092417 - Executing: cf login -u chrisr@ca.ibm.com -o chrisr@ca.ibm.com -s dev -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net
API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net`

Password> 
Authenticating...
OK

Targeted org chrisr@ca.ibm.com

Targeted space dev



API endpoint:   https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.40.0)   
User:           chrisr@ca.ibm.com   
Org:            chrisr@ca.ibm.com   
Space:          dev   
@2015-11-26 01:38:32.186204 - cf exit level: 0
@2015-11-26 01:38:32.186340 - config.json path: /root/.cf/config.json
@2015-11-26 01:38:32.186640 - Bearer: <long string omitted>
@2015-11-26 01:38:32.186697 - cf login succeeded. Can access: https://api-ice.ng.bluemix.net/v3/containers
Authentication with container cloud service at https://api-ice.ng.bluemix.net/v3/containers completed successfully
You can issue commands now to the container service

Proceeding to authenticate with the container cloud registry at registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net
@2015-11-26 01:38:32.187317 - using bearer token
@2015-11-26 01:38:32.187350 - config.json path: /root/.cf/config.json
@2015-11-26 01:38:32.187489 - Bearer: <long pw string omitted>
@2015-11-26 01:38:32.187517 - Org Guid: dae00d7c-1c3d-4bfd-a207-57a35a2fb42b
@2015-11-26 01:38:32.187551 - docker login -u bearer -p '<long pw string omitted>' -e a@b.c registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net
FATA[0012] Error response from daemon: </html>          
@2015-11-26 01:38:44.689721 - docker call exit level: 256
docker is not available on your system or is not properly configured
Could not authenticate with cloud registry at registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net 
You can still use IBM Containers but will not be able to run local docker containers, push, or pull images
@2015-11-26 01:38:44.689842 - Exit err level = 2**
```

On the other box, it also fails, but the final error is slightly different.

```
@2015-11-26 01:44:48.916034 - docker login -u bearer -p '<long pw string omitted>' -e a@b.c registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net
Error response from daemon: Unexpected status code [502] : <html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
@2015-11-26 01:45:02.582753 - docker call exit level: 256
docker is not available on your system or is not properly configured
Could not authenticate with cloud registry at registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net 
You can still use IBM Containers but will not be able to run local docker containers, push, or pull images
@2015-11-26 01:45:02.582868 - Exit err level = 2
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing these issues?

Answer (score 4):

The errors are referring the same problem, ice isn't finding any docker env locally.
It doesn't prevent working remotely on Bluemix but without a local docker env ice cannot work with local containers

Comment: prerequisites here:     Docker version 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, or 1.8.1 --
    Python version 2.7 or later -- 
    Python Setuptools version 2.7 or later --
    Python Pip version 2.7 or later --
    IBM Containers Extension (ice) 3.0 --
    Cloud Foundry CLI version 6.12.0 and later

Comment: But docker is there, on both boxes, though different versions.  

[root@cds-legacy-monitor ~]# docker version
Client version: 1.6.0
Client API version: 1.18
...
[root@cds-legacy-monitor ~]# docker search centos
NAME                                        DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
centos                                      The official build of CentOS.                   1666      [OK]

The docker command is running, but its not connecting to the ICS docker registry and its giving a rather inaccurate error at the end.

Comment: I suppose you are still missing something and it prevents you from login successfully.

Comment: From Bluemix containers doc to use ice "Note: You must ensure that the Cloud Foundry command tool (cf) is installed, as well as the Docker CLI (docker), and that they are both on your environment path."

Comment: Could you check you have cf and its containers plugin correctly installed? If so could you try running simple "ice login" command to login step by step? The parameters you are setting are the Bluemix default ones.

Comment: Crescenzo helped me yesterday.  It looks like my version of both ice and cf were too old so I upgraded and things are working better.  Thanks for your help.